# Formula to return the value from cell x in cell y when value entered in cell z

Tags: google-sheets, formula, return-value, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have an attendance sheet and row 6 has class dates and teachers enter attendance using rows 7 on. When a teacher enters "ED" or enrolls date in the attendance, I want the corresponding date to appear in Column AJ. For example, if Student A (row 7) has an ED on 10/12/19, I want "10/12/19" to appear in the corresponding row in AJ7.

I tried writing an `IF`/`IFS` formula, but can't seem to figure out how to pull the corresponding date and as the value for column Z. I tried the formula `=IF(Z8:AI8 = "ED",Z7:AI7, " ")`, but it returned an error message that an array value could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

try if this works for you:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Z8:AI8="ED", Z7:AI7, ))
```

Comment: It works, but the only hitch is that I can't have any data after that column.

Answer (score 1):

Different interpretation of requirement. In AJ7 and copied down to suit:

```
=index($Z$6:$AI$6,match("ED",Z7:AI7,0))
```